# ggplot - abline disappears when limiting x and y

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data:

```
set.seed(123456)
Test_1 <- round(rnorm(20,mean=40,sd=5),0)/100
Test_2 <- round(rnorm(20,mean=60,sd=5),0)/100
ei.data <- as.data.frame(cbind(Test_1,Test_2))

 intercept <- as.data.frame(matrix(0,20,1))
  slope <- as.data.frame(matrix(0,20,1))
  data <- cbind(intercept,slope)
  colnames(data) <- c("intercept","slope")
  for (i in 1:nrow(ei.data)){
    data[i,1] <- (ei.data[i,2]/(1-ei.data[i,1]))
    data[i,2] <- (ei.data[i,2]/(1-ei.data[i,2]))
  }
```

Now I want to plot the data from the ei.data data frame in a point plot and then add the date from the data data frame in form of lines using `abline`.

```
ei <- ggplot(ei.data, aes(Test_1,Test_2))+
  geom_point()+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1))+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1))+
  geom_abline(slope =data[1,2] , intercept =data[1,1])
ei
```

However, the problem I have is, that if I limit `x` and `y` scale to `[0,1]` the line I created using `abline` disappears. How can I still plot the lines even when I am limiting `x` and `y`?

Comment: you are zooming on a region which your abline does not cross... so it will nog be visible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment on your question already says, zooming in on that part of your region will make your abline always dissapear to the greatest extend. So this answer might not be 100% satisfying. Still, what you can do is to change the limits nevertheless or you can highlight the small section of your abline so that it becomes visible more easily without changing the limits.

Here's an example:

```
# Changing the limits
ggplot(ei.data, aes(Test_1,Test_2))+
  geom_point()+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 2))+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 2))+
  geom_abline(slope =data[1,2] , intercept =data[1,1])
```

[image]

```
# Not changing the limits, but making it visible more easily
ggplot(ei.data, aes(Test_1,Test_2))+
  geom_point()+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1))+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1))+
  geom_abline(slope =data[1,2] , intercept =data[1,1],
              color="red", size=2)+
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0.2, y = 0.75, xend = 0.05, yend = 0.9),
               colour='red', size=2,arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.5, "cm")))+
  annotate("text", label="Mind the abline!", x=0.25, y=0.74)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I cannot change the limits, because it has to be from [0,1]. Only a small part of the abline is exactly what I want. However, for some reason it just does not show up on my plot.

Comment: Ok, that's what I expected. Did you try to highlight it as shown above? Do you at least see the arrow?

Comment: I see the arrow and the text, but highlighting does not work.

Comment: That's really strange. Did you try to copy and paste my code 1:1? Does the abline still dissapear? Maybe there's a typo in your code. If it's still not there, do you see it when changing the scale for bugfixing purposes?

Comment: I copied and pasted your code 1:1 now and it worked. Must have been a typo in my code. But it works now! Thank you very much!